# Assumptions used for Designing Homomorphic CRHF

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, homomorphic-signatures

What are the possible assumptions that have been used or can be used for designing the homomorphic Collision Resistant Hash function (CRHF)? I know Short Integer Solution (SIS) is one of the assumptions used for designing homomorphic CRHF.

Comment: After some searching, I guess the vocabulary in the question is aligned with [this](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/papers/otfvec/paper.pdf#page=4).

Comment: The Pedersen hash is homomorphic and collision resistant based on discrete log.